# Marking nested makes terms query and aggregation not working

Tags: elasticsearch

to achieve proper query on attributes array , i declared the field as nested. Now the terms query nor the normal match query is not giving any results. Is there something i should do specific about this type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this working , you need to use

1. [Nested query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) for querying nested fields
2. [Nested filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-nested-filter.html) for filtering
3. [Nested aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) for aggregation

This is due to the change that the for each element in the nested array , a new nested lucene document is made and you need separate set of query/agg to access them. Else it looks in the root document , where it is not present.